# JTable removing row gives ArrayOutofBounds exception -1

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception, tablemodel

I have been browsing numerous sites about this and tried some different things but im stumped. Would be grateful for some help.
The condition is working that checks if a checkbox is selected (true) but soon as I do model.removeRow(row) it gives me this error.

```
public class ExpenditurePanel extends JPanel implements TableModelListener{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static TableModel1 model;
private JTable table;

public ExpenditurePanel() {
    model = new TableModel1();
    table = new JTable(model);
    table.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);

    model.addColumn("Name");
    model.addColumn("Week");
    model.addColumn("Fortnight");
    model.addColumn("Month");
    model.addColumn("Year");
    model.addColumn("Remove");

    Object[] default1 = {"Accomodation","","","","",false};
    Object[] default2 = {"Food","","","","",false};

    model.addRow(default1);
    model.addRow(default2);

    model.addTableModelListener(this);

    this.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    table.setRowSorter(null);

}

public static TableModel1 getModel(){
    return model;
}

@Override
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    int row = e.getFirstRow();
    int column = e.getColumn();
    model = (TableModel1) e.getSource();
    String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
    Object data = model.getValueAt(row, column);

    if(model.getValueAt(row,column) == Boolean.TRUE){
        System.out.println("Condition working");

        //this part keeps giving me error.
        model.removeRow(row);
    }
}
}
```

This is what it throws out:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.Vector.elementData(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
at studentBudget.ExpenditurePanel.tableChanged(ExpenditurePanel.java:53)
at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableRowsDeleted(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.removeRow(Unknown Source)
at studentBudget.ExpenditurePanel.tableChanged(ExpenditurePanel.java:59)
at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableCellUpdated(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setValueAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.editingStopped(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor.fireEditingStopped(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor$EditorDelegate.stopCellEditing(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor.stopCellEditing(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor$EditorDelegate.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.repostEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: See **Edit 2** to answer that provides a possible solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing the TableModel inside of a TableModelListener and that seems just a bit risky to me and is a risk for unwanted recursion. I would re-factor your code so as not to do this if possible. If you're still stuck, then you should create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

---

**Edit 1**

If I make an [sscce](http://sscce.org) out of your code and add println statements:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class ExpenditurePanel extends JPanel implements TableModelListener {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private static TableModel1 model;
   private JTable table;

   public ExpenditurePanel() {
      model = new TableModel1();
      table = new JTable(model);
      table.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null,
            null));
      table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
      table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
      table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
      table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);

      model.addColumn("Name");
      model.addColumn("Week");
      model.addColumn("Fortnight");
      model.addColumn("Month");
      model.addColumn("Year");
      model.addColumn("Remove");

      Object[] default1 = { "Accomodation", "", "", "", "", false };
      Object[] default2 = { "Food", "", "", "", "", false };

      model.addRow(default1);
      model.addRow(default2);

      model.addTableModelListener(this);

      this.add(new JScrollPane(table));
      table.setRowSorter(null);

   }

   public static TableModel1 getModel() {
      return model;
   }

   @Override
   public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
      int row = e.getFirstRow();
      int column = e.getColumn();

      // **** printf added below
      System.out.printf("[row: %d, column: %d]%n", row, column);

      model = (TableModel1) e.getSource();

      String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);

      // **** println added below
      System.out.println("columnName: " + columnName);

      Object data = model.getValueAt(row, column);

      if (model.getValueAt(row, column) == Boolean.TRUE) {
         System.out.println("Condition working");

         // *** AIOOBE called here
         model.removeRow(row);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            ExpenditurePanel panel = new ExpenditurePanel();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("foo");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }
}

// **** no idea how close this is to your code *****
class TableModel1 extends DefaultTableModel {
   @Override
   public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
      if (getRowCount() == 0) {
         return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
      }
      Object value = getValueAt(0, columnIndex);
      if (value == null) {
         return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
      }

      return value.getClass();
   }
}
```

---

I get this output:

```
[row: 0, column: 5]
columnName: Remove
Condition working
[row: 0, column: -1]
columnName: 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
    ...... etc ......
```

So you see the model listener's `tableChanged(...)` method is called ***twice*** due to a recursion occurring from changing the listened to object inside of the listener, and the second time it's called, it has a column of -1 which causes your AIOOBE to be thrown.

---

**Edit 2**
A potential solution is to remove the listener before making the change to the model and then re-adding the listener after making the change:

```
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
  int row = e.getFirstRow();
  int column = e.getColumn();
  System.out.printf("[row: %d, column: %d]%n", row, column);
  model = (TableModel1) e.getSource();
  String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
  System.out.println("columnName: " + columnName);
  Object data = model.getValueAt(row, column);

  if (model.getValueAt(row, column) == Boolean.TRUE) {
     System.out.println("Condition working");

     model.removeTableModelListener(this);
     model.removeRow(row);
     model.addTableModelListener(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its working now from your potential solution. Ill go over what you said and see if I can understand why it was doing that. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @Sam: you're welcome. The problem is that your code changes the table's model which triggers the TableModelListener, which changes the table's model which triggers the.... etc... see where I'm going?

Comment: +1 for the trackdown, -1 for the solution, zeros out in votes :-)

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a bit on @Hover's correct trackdown and assuming a valid use-case like "we have a list of jobs, if done with one remove that job it from the list":

The base problem with your listener is that it doesn't check which type of change it is notified with: you are interested only in the update of a particular column, not in any other (fi. like the removal the row), that causes the error on the second notification: a modelEvent of typ removed has a column of -1

The solution is to add the check and do nothing if trigger wasn't an update on the specific column:

```
@Override
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    if (!TableUtilities.isUpdate(e)) return;
    ...  
}
```

Analysing a TableModelEvent is a bit inconvenient (not entirely intuitive conditions, requires thorough reading of the TableModelEvent javadoc) - which I'm too lazy to keep it in memory, so  there's a utility class in [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net), the relevant parts copied here for convenience:

```
/**
 * Returns a boolean indication whether the event represents a
 * dataChanged type.
 * 
 * @param e the event to examine.
 * @return true if the event is of type dataChanged, false else.
 */
public static boolean isDataChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    if (e == null)
        return false;
    return e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE && e.getFirstRow() == 0
            && e.getLastRow() == Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}

/**
 * Returns a boolean indication whether the event represents a
 * update type.
 * 
 * @param e the event to examine.
 * @return true if the event is a true update, false
 *         otherwise.
 */
public static boolean isUpdate(TableModelEvent e) {
    if (isStructureChanged(e))
        return false;
    return e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE
            && e.getLastRow() < Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}

/**
 * Returns a boolean indication whether the event represents a
 * insert type.
 * 
 * @param e the event to examine
 * @return true if the event is of type insert, false otherwise.
 */
public static boolean isInsert(TableModelEvent e) {
    if (e == null) return false;
    return TableModelEvent.INSERT == e.getType();
}


/**
 * Returns a boolean indication whether the event represents a
 * structureChanged type.
 * 
 * @param e the event to examine.
 * @return true if the event is of type structureChanged or null, false
 *         else.
 */
public static boolean isStructureChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    return e == null || e.getFirstRow() == TableModelEvent.HEADER_ROW;
}
```

Comment: 1+ for educating me as always, thanks! Sorry to jump off-topic, but please weigh in on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17626773/522444) discussion in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just make so:

```
clsController.getTable().setSortable( false );
model.removeRow( selectedModelRow );
clsController.getTable().setSortable( true );
```

and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can check its event type.
Doing so, you can skip the content of the tableChanged method for add and delete.

```
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    int type = e.getType();

    if (type != TableModelEvent.DELETE && type != TableModelEvent.INSERT) {

    // operation only for update

    }
}
```